# Does SSIS provides any kind of encryption on the wire

Tags: sql-server, ssis, azure-sql-database

Currently we have a process of transferring data from on-perm server (limited set of table) to SQL Azure using SSIS. I was just wondering is there any provision in SSIS where we can encrypt the data on wire as its gets copied from one database to the other.

Comment: You set up SQL Server to use SSL then in your SSIS connection manager you tell it to use an encrypted connection. It's not an SSIS specific thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All connections to Azure SQL Database are encrypted by default and unencrypted connections are rejected.

When SSIS connects to Azure SQL Database, the destination database will negotiate SSL before the login process and all subsequent interactions will be encrypted.